# How to add ws-security in SoapUI JAX-WS generated code

Tags: java, soap, soapui, ws-security, ws-addressing

I create a project in SoapUi from a WSDL where the request must have ws-addressing and ws-security.

The question is where I have to configure SoapUI to add ws-security and ws-addressing so the generator takes that values and include in the Java clasess that creates.

I did it first on the request soap message, but generator didnt use it. Then I added to the Outgoing WS-Security Configurations, but the same result. The clases are the same as if I never set that conf.

What I m missing?

Comment: Which type of artifacts do you generate?

Comment: I choose JAX-WS artifacts and then I complete WSDL, TargetDirectory, Package and SourceDirectory.

Comment: Do you use basic authentication with username-password? Do you want to set authentication credentials such as usr/pwd?

Comment: I want to set user and pass, and to and action tags in generated clases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]

wsimport must have generated a service port class that's name suffix is "_Service".

```
YourServiceName_Service svcPort;

// ....

Map<String, Object> request = ((BindingProvider) svcPort).getRequestContext();
request.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "<username>");
request.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "<password>");
```

---

You must set ws-security credentials on base classes of autogenerated classes. This example may help you

http://java.globinch.com/enterprise-java/web-services/jax-ws/secure-usernametoken-java-web-services-using-metro-wsit/#jax-ws-usernametoken-client-example

Comment: But this is using WSIT. At the moment, I m not using it. It is required to do what I want?

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. BindingProvider also have the properties for ws-addressing.